# Ruby on Rails: Redirecting with an associated id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect

I have two tables, `lists` and `ideas` where they're in relation to each other.

**lists**

```
has_many :ideas
```

**ideas**

```
belongs_to :lists
```

I have a text field in my lists page (for my ideas), under `localhost:3000/lists/1` and when I click on create idea, it takes me to ideas/1, or ideas/2, etc... and this is all associated to the list id 1. What I'm trying to do is dynamically redirect back to `localhost:3000/lists/1`

I have this:

```
redirect_to(:controller => 'lists', :action => 'show')
```

within my ideas controller.

But this redirect gives me errors because its looking for List with id=#, because the id is being generated with the ideas controller and associated it with my lists page

How do I redirect back to its associated List id? (in this example, it should go back to list/1

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to redirect back:

```
#Method 1
redirect_to @idea.list

#Method 2
redirect_to :back
```

All should work in your case.

Comment: Oh interesting... is there any way of understanding how it works? Or is this that "magic" that i always read about RoR

Comment: @andrewliu, they are not magic, all documented in api: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html The first method is about "Record - The URL will be generated by calling url_for with the options, which will reference a named URL for that record.". The second: ":back - Back to the page that issued the request."